# Turtle not running

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I wrote this code for turtle but it is not working and I can't figure out what's wrong. I have confirmed that turtle is working because I can run simpler graphics. I'm a total beginner so please excuse my oversight if its something simple.
Thanks!

```
import turtle
import sys
import math

def drawSquare(t,sideLength):
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(sideLength)
        t.right(90)

def main():
    sideLength = int(sys.argv[1])

    draw = turtle.Turtle()

    drawSquare(draw,sideLength)

    turtle.exitonclick

    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably had some typos. I fixed `exitonclick()` to actually be a function, not object by adding the parenthesis. Then, `main()` should be placed outside the `def main()` scope so that Python knows to call main in the first place.

Secondly, `exitonclick` refers to a window in order to close that window. That is why you need to create a window first, then close that window on click. See `wn = turtle.Screen()`

```
import turtle
import sys
import math

def drawSquare(t,sideLength):
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(sideLength)
        t.right(90)

def main():
    wn=turtle.Screen()
    sideLength = int(sys.argv[1])
    draw = turtle.Turtle()
    drawSquare(draw,sideLength)

    wn.exitonclick()

main()
```

Comment: So now I don't get any error messages on the terminal but the turtle window doesn't show up when I hit enter

Comment: Are you running the script with a parameter such as python name.py 200 ?

Comment: Yes I run "python3 drawflower.py 100"

Comment: I see no problem with the code. Runs fine on my end. Can you provide any error messages?

Comment: Nop no error messages. I guess its just my laptop. I'll find another computer since I've already been having issues with this one already. Thanks!

Comment: Did it work? If this answer helped, please accept it as a solution.